# Put some elements from component into head tag

Tags: astrojs

I want that some tags from component to go to `head` tag.
I want to put in the `slot` named `head`.
How could achieve this ?

layout.astro

```
<html>
    <head>
        <slot name="head" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <slot />
        <mycomponent />
    </body>
</html>
```

mycomponent.astro

```
<link .... slot="head">
<div>
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

It is possible to place a tag, but only from where you call a Layout where the single `<head>` is placed, using `slots` like this

in the Layout.astro you create a

- default slot and
- a named slot e.g. `name="head"` but you could use any name

```js
    <head>
        <title>{title}</title>
        <slot name="head"/>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <slot />
    </body>
```

then in your page or in the Component that is calling the Layout

```js
<Layout title="Welcome to Astro.">
    <link slot="head" rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/favicon.svg" />
    <main>
        <h1>Astro</h1>
    </main>
</Layout>
```

### Clarifications

- The slot concept is independent from the Layout and head
- The Layout component can have any name and can be used from any component
- In Astro there can be only one single `<head>` element per page, all other used `<head>` tags will stay where they are and will not be moved by the compiler to the main top `<head>`
- A page and all of its children components can use the slot concept to fill it tags inside the single parent `<head>` tag via slots
- This only works if the component directly includes the component e.g. Layout that is providing the slots

### References

Note : The reference below from the Astro Documentation website recommends to "place the single `<head>` and its contents in a layout component."

https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/troubleshooting/#using-head-in-a-component

named slots :https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/astro-components/#named-slots

Comment: Thank you! This will work I just wonder if it's possible out of the box from compent to parent

Comment: no, directly from component to parent without slots is not possible, I provided a reference from astro doc that state it.